# Connecting Win 10 roadwarrior to AWS strongSwan VPN - not able to find a certificate usable with Extensible Authentication Protocol

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, vpn, strongswan

I managed to connect two AWS subnets in different zones over strongSwan VPN using ike2 with the aes256 encryption. So, Master CA key is created, self-signed CA certificate, as well as private and public keys for both gateways. After that, I created certificates for the roadwarrior and export them to win10 client in the p12 format.

The connection between those two LANs are working, but I am not able to attach the roadwarrior client.

I imported the certificates into win10 and they are normally visible in the certification manager.

Then I created VPN configuration using Windows10 VPN client, and when I run it I got from the Windows message:

A certificate could not be found that can be used with this Extensible Authentication Protocol.

Checking in `certmagr` everything is in the place.

The authentication method used is EAP-tls and it is working without a problem in LAN to LAN model.

Win10 VPN security property setup is:

`Type of the VPN: IKE2 ,
Data Encryption: Require encryption (disconnect if server declines)
Authentication: Use Extensible Authentication Protocol 
-> Microsoft smart card or other certificates (encryption enabled)
    -> Properties
    ---> Use certificate on this computer
    ---> Verify the server's identity by validating the certificate
    ---> Trusted Root Certificate authority
    ----> Both certificates CA and the client p12 certificate are visible
          and checked`

Here is **the ipsec.conf** file

```
config setup
    charondebug="cfg 2, dmn 2, ike 2,net 2"
    uniqueids=yes
    strictcrlpolicy=no

conn %default
    fragmentation=force
    forceencaps=yes
    rekeymargin=3m
    mobike=no
    keyingtries=%forever
    ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha2_256-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sh256,aes256-sha2_256!
    ikelifetime=1h
    lifetime=8h
    dpddelay=30
    dpdtimeout=120
    dpdaction=restart
    authby=pubkey
    leftcert=vpn-west-public-certificate.pem
    leftsendcert=always
    keyexchange=ikev2
    type=tunnel
    leftca="C=DE, O=Orgname, CN=Orgname Root CA"
    leftid=13.57.xx.yy
    left=10.0.0.208
    leftsubnet=10.0.0.0/16

conn roadw
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-tls
    rightsourceip=10.0.0.64/28
    rightsendcert=never
    rightdns=8.8.8.8
    eap_identity=%identity
    auto=add
```

Here is the **IPsec.secrets** file

```
13.57.xx.yy : RSA "/etc/ipsec.d/private/vpn-west-private-key.pem"
username : EAP "passphrase"
```

CA root is installed in the client, as well the username.p12. I suspect there are some tweaks on both sides' Linux and Windows.

Further, I found that the Windows requires the Hostname or IP Address to be listed part of the ipsec pki -- issuer arguments in a form --san dns:13.57.xx.yy during public server certificate creation, as well client (windows) user certificate need to have as CN=$USER" --san $USER. I added both parameters but still, there is no change in the behavior.

Do I need to add extKeyUsage, OID has to be 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2, since adding it did not change anything.

Any idea where to start, it looks that windows10 is not even starting the session, therefore it looks to me that something is wrong with the configuration of the VPN client at the Win10, as well some parameters should be tweaked at the strongSwan side too.

Here are the certificates config commands for the CA, server and client

**Root Master key**

```
ipsec pki --gen --type rsa --size 4096 --outform > root-key-for-ca=signing.pem
```

**Root CA certificate**

```
ipsec pki --self --ca --lifetime 3650 --in root-key-for-ca=signing.pem --type rsa --dn "C=DE, O=Orgname Root CA" --outform pem > signed-root-ca-certificate.pem
```

**Client private key**

```
ipsec pki --gen --type rsa --size 2048 --outform pem > win10-client1-key.pem
```

**Client public certificate**

```
ipsec pki --pub --in win10-client1-key.pem --type rsa | ipsec pki --issue --lifetime 730 --cacert signed-root-ca-certificate.pem --cakey root-key-for-ca-signing.pem --dn "C=DE, O=Orgname, CN=win10-client1" --san "win10-client1" --flag serverAuth --flag clientAuth --flag ikeIntermediate --outform pem > vpn-win10-client1-public-certificate.pem
```

**P12 portable format for transferring of the client personal private keys**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey win10-client1-key.pem -in vpn-win10-client1-public-certificate.pem -name "win10-client1 VPN certificate" -certfile signed-root-ca-certificate.pem -cname "Orgname Root CA" -out win10-client1.p12
```

**Private server key**

```
ipsec pki --gen --type rsa --size 2048 --outform pem > vpn-west=private-key.pem
```

Public server certificate

```
ipsec pki --pub --in vpn-west-private-key.pem --type rsa | ipsec pki --issue --lifetime 730 --cacert signed-root-ca-certificate.pem --cakey root-key-for-ca-signing.pem --dn "C=DE, O=Orgname, CN=13.57.xx.yy" --san 13.57.xx.yy --san dns:13.57.xx.yy --flag serverAuth --flag ikeIntermediate --outform pem > vpn-west-public-certificate.pem
```

Comment: You probably messed up your certificates somehow (DN, SAN, flags, keys...). Without information on these we can't really help you. See [this page](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Win7CertReq) on the strongSwan wiki for some pointers (in particular the section about client certificates, if you intend to use EAP-TLS).

Comment: It is just testing configuration, therefore, I can send the configuration sequences

Comment: Could be due to the _serverAuth_ flag you set in the client certificate (you also won't need the _ikeIntermediate_ flag there). Or you maybe installed the certs in the wrong location (user vs. computer account certificate store, must be the former for EAP-TLS, or the CA cert in the wrong directory in the cert store).

Comment: Thanks, ecdsa at your comment. I will remove the serverAuth flag as well ikeIntermediate, that could be an issue, Regarding the location of the certificate they are in the computer account store, will add graphics of the position of the certificates.  What you mean with the: "must be in the former for EAP-TLS".

Comment: To use EAP-TLS the certificates have to be stored in the certificate store of the user account, not that of the computer/machine (the latter must be the case for machine certificate authentication, i.e. regular IKEv2 certificate authentication, no EAP involved). See [this page](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/WindowsClients) on the wiki for more information.